# cgroup IO control v.s. (the new types of) Linux AIO

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, io, cgroups

In Linux v5.0, do some types of Asynchronous IO bypass the cgroup IO controllers?

EDIT: buffered write() and fsync() might be relatively complex to analyse.  I found an interesting post about controlling buffered writes here: https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/.  If this question seems too complex, perhaps it would be simplest to start off asking about buffered read() with `io_uring`.

---

The new AIO interface `io_uring` includes AIO equivalents of read(), write(), and also fsync().  When you use it for "buffered IO" (normal cachable file IO), and the IO cannot be satisfied immediately by the page cache, it runs asynchronously using workqueues.

Also the original AIO system call `io_submit()` recently [gained support for `IOCB_CMD_FSYNC`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a3c0d439e4d92411c2b4b21a526a4de720d0806b#diff-66ae2137a5e92e3df73e350aecf5388b).  This new command uses workqueues to call vfs_fsync().  (Dave Chinner strongly implies [`IOCB_CMD_FSYNC` works for normal "buffered IO"](https://lwn.net/Articles/789195/), so it sounds quite similar to `io_uring`).

`IOCB_CMD_FSYNC` uses the kernel default workqueue.  `io_uring` is slightly different.  Each `io_uring` creates its own concurrency-managed workqueue ([cmwq](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/core-api/workqueue.html)).

I looked at `ps -eo pid,user,args,cgroup|grep [[]` on my system.  The only kernel thread inside a cgroup happened to be `[vhost-nnn]`.  I found the kernel explicitly places these vhost_worker threads inside the cgroup of the user process which created them.  See [vhost_attach_cgroups_work()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/drivers/vhost/vhost.c#L467).

In contrast, there is no mention of `cgroup`'s in [fs/io_uring.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/fs/io_uring.c#L828), nor in [kernel/workqueue.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/kernel/workqueue.c).

[struct file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/include/linux/fs.h#L901) does not directly point to a specific cgroup.  Although it does points to a [struct inode](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/include/linux/fs.h#L603), which points to "the associated cgroup wb" if `CONFIG_CGROUP_WRITEBACK` is set.